# how to get virtual fields in aggregation query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

i have model with one virtual field `show`:

```
modelSchema.virtual('show').get(function () {
    return true
})
```

now, when I use query in nodeJS with `find` like this:

```
model.find({"$license_id": license_id})
```

In result, I have the virtual field `show`.

but

if I use query with `aggregation`  like this :

```
model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$license_id", license_id] }
        }
    }
])
```

In result, I don't have the virtual field `show`.

how to get the virtual fields in `aggregation` queries?
Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) or [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) stages to include the field in aggregation. [Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) are properties not persisted in the database. You have to try a function to get the required value.

```
model.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$license_id", license_id] }
        }
    },
   $addFields: {
        show: true
    }
])
```